# Hibernate huge memory allocation with join fetch

Tags: java, hibernate, join, memory

I'm trying to increase the performance of an application, so the first thing we did was look at the database queries to optimize them.

One of the thing we did was adding "join fetch" and "left join fetch" where appropriate to remove the N+1 queries.

Another was to retrieve results in bulk (`select distinct stuff from stuff left join fetch other_stuff where id in (?1)`) instead of for loops retrieving results one by one (`for (id: ids) select distinct stuff from stuff left join fetch other_stuff where id = ?1`).

The problem is that, while our queries are much faster and our database load is much lower, it seems hibernate needs a lot more memory to do that.

When profiling the application, I can see that the number of objects allocated per second is upward of 500 000. The garbage collector can't keep up and the application freezes and eventually makes an OutOfMemory.

From the hprof, most of the objects seem allocated in hibernate classes. The worst offender seems to be the bulk the query `select where id in (?1)`. It is executed once per second, retrieve around 500 objects, but seems responsible for around 300 000 objects allocation per second.

My guess is that due to the joins, the database returns 300 000+ lines (that's indeed what I get when I manually run `select count(*) from stuff join other_stuff`), that hibernate must all allocate before consolidating all that in my final 500 objects.

Am I right?

I guess not doing the `left join fetch` and letting hibernate load them with a separate query would drastically reduce that allocation, but it hurts the performance.

Is there a way to reduce that memory allocation while still fetching immediately?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 different fetch strategies in Hibernate that you can use, although only join fetching can be specified in a query. The others are just annotated and take effect during lazy loading.

- `JOIN` fetch in SQL joins which might result in N * M result set explosion like you figured
- `SUBSELECT` execute one query for the association by embedding the main query
- `SELECT` (default) issues a select by id query for every N elements from the main query where N is the configured batch size. This is a good strategy if your main query is very complex query and thus `SUBSELECT` is not appropriate. It's recommended to align the batch size with the amount of elements you usually expect in the main query to avoid executing too many queries.

Usually, I recommend `SUBSELECT` fetching, unless the query takes too long or the amount of elements your main query produces can be estimated.

Other performance improvements can be achieved by reducing the amount of select items, but this requires creating custom DTO models.

I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A sample DTO model could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(User.class)
public interface UserDto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    String getName();
    Set<RoleDto> getRoles();

    @EntityView(Role.class)
    interface RoleDto {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
        String getName();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`UserDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, UserDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

Even if the `User` or `Role` entities contain many more columns, by using Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views only the data that is actually needed will be fetched.

Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views has similar fetch strategies like Hibernate and also has another one called `MULTISET`, which is the best of them all. It will make use of JSON or String aggregation functions on the DBMS side to flatten joins into a single column. This avoids the N * M result set explosion and at the same time, still executes in a single query. Here the documentation about the fetch strategies: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/#anchor-fetch-strategies